# Halachic view on the order of personal effort vs prayers

Tags: halacha, tefilla, health-safety-shmira

In my previous question "[yaakov-preceded-his-effort-to-a-prayer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110311/why-yaakov-preceded-his-effort-to-a-prayer)" we see that Yaakov, hearing the bad news preferred to make the effort first and daven later.

It made me think: this happens to me a lot, for example, my kid says "my back hurts, I need to see a doctor", my other kid says "my car's stuck I need to fix it" or my wife says "my credit card was declined, we need to check our balance".

What does the Halachah say about what should precede what - pray first and act later or act and then pray? Does it depend on its urgency, like rushing into emergency room or setting an appointment for the next week? Does it differentiate between health and monetary issues?